# How do I query unique documents from a meteor collection and avoid duplicates?

Tags: meteor

I have a collection that contains thousands of documents in this form:

```
{
"_id": "wMRHDpb53RhhjxXj4",
"institution": "uw.edu",
"campus": "seattle",
"quarter": "SUMMER",
"department": "CHEM",
"course": "CHEM321",
"section": "A",
"ISBN": "",
"createdAt": {
    "$date": "2017-08-13T18:20:40.923Z"
},
"ilendBooksId": "none",
"ilendbooksId": "none"
```

}

Each document represents a course at my school.
EDIT: I have multiple documents that share every field except the date created. Based on that, what is the best solution? 
I only want one document of each document that may exist of a different course. Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There [is a mongo query identifier](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/), called `.distinct()` that supports retrieving unique entries. So you can e.g. retrieve all possible names of courses without duplicates.

Unfortunately it is only implemented in more recent mongo versions and yet not supported in minimongo (the client side implementation of mongodb in meteor).

If there is progress on that, this answer will be updated. Please comment, if this is deprecated.

However, there is already an [open github feature request](https://github.com/meteor/meteor-feature-requests/issues/159) on that.